# Using beautifulsoup to extract text between line breaks (e.g. <br /> tags)

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML that is within a larger document

```
<br />
Important Text 1
<br />
<br />
Not Important Text
<br />
Important Text 2
<br />
Important Text 3
<br />
<br />
Non Important Text
<br />
Important Text 4
<br />
```

I'm currently using BeautifulSoup to obtain other elements within the HTML, but I have not been able to find a way to get the important lines of text between `<br />` tags. I can isolate and navigate to each of the `<br />` elements, but can't find a way to get the text in between. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you just want any text which is between two `<br />` tags, you could do something like the following:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag

input = '''<br />
Important Text 1
<br />
<br />
Not Important Text
<br />
Important Text 2
<br />
Important Text 3
<br />
<br />
Non Important Text
<br />
Important Text 4
<br />'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(input)

for br in soup.findAll('br'):
    next_s = br.nextSibling
    if not (next_s and isinstance(next_s,NavigableString)):
        continue
    next2_s = next_s.nextSibling
    if next2_s and isinstance(next2_s,Tag) and next2_s.name == 'br':
        text = str(next_s).strip()
        if text:
            print "Found:", next_s
```

But perhaps I misunderstand your question?  Your description of the problem doesn't seem to match up with the "important" / "non important" in your example data, so I've gone with the description ;)

Comment: Ahh, the problem was I was using findNextSibling(), and that was just skipping over the text and going to the next line break. Using nextSibling worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great answer, this saved me a lot of headache!

Comment: Is `next` not a reserved word in Python? Perhaps a different variable name would be better? (This is a minor point, but such things add up!)

Comment: duhaime: it isn't a keyword in Python, in fact (`continue` is the Python equivalent of `next` in other languages)

Comment: Mark, this worked fine EXCEPT it returned text 2 thru n. I'm still trying to get the first text which END with "<br/>"

Comment: @MarkLongair `next` might not be a 'keyword' like `for` or `if`, but it is a built-in function and will be reassigned in the above implementation. Thus advancing an iterator using `my_val = next(my_generator)` will fail after the reassigment. Using `next` as a variable name is IMO inadvisable. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next

Comment: @André Christoffer Andersen: of course, yes, good point! I've changed that in the answer so it doesn't shadow the built-in function.

Answer (score 8):

So, for test purposes, let's assume that this chunk of HTML is inside a `span` tag:

```
x = """<span><br />
Important Text 1
<br />
<br />
Not Important Text
<br />
Important Text 2
<br />
Important Text 3
<br />
<br />
Non Important Text
<br />
Important Text 4
<br /></span>"""
```

Now I'm going to parse it and find my span tag:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
y = soup.find('span')
```

If you iterate over the generator in `y.childGenerator()`, you will get both the br's and the text:

```
In [4]: for a in y.childGenerator(): print type(a), str(a)
   ....: 
<type 'instance'> <br />
<class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'> 
Important Text 1

<type 'instance'> <br />
<class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'> 

<type 'instance'> <br />
<class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'> 
Not Important Text

<type 'instance'> <br />
<class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'> 
Important Text 2

<type 'instance'> <br />
<class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'> 
Important Text 3

<type 'instance'> <br />
<class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'> 

<type 'instance'> <br />
<class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'> 
Non Important Text

<type 'instance'> <br />
<class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'> 
Important Text 4

<type 'instance'> <br />
```

Answer (score 3):

A slight improvement to Ken Kinder's answer. You can instead access the `stripped_strings` attribute of the BeautifulSoup element. For example, let's say your particular chunk of HTML is inside a `span` tag:

```
x = """<span><br />
Important Text 1
<br />
<br />
Not Important Text
<br />
Important Text 2
<br />
Important Text 3
<br />
<br />
Non Important Text
<br />
Important Text 4
<br /></span>"""
```

First we parse `x` with BeautifulSoup. Then look for the element, in this case `span`, and then access the `stripped_strings` attribute. Like so,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(x)
span = soup.find("span")
text = list(span.stripped_strings)
```

Now `print(text)` will give the following output:

```
['Important Text 1',
 'Not Important Text',
 'Important Text 2',
 'Important Text 3',
 'Non Important Text',
 'Important Text 4']
```

Comment: I get 'list' object is not callable on this

Comment: The code works fine for me. On which line do you get this error?

Comment: This does not break the text along just `<br>` but all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
for br in soup.findAll('br'):
    if str(type(br.contents[0])) == '<class \'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString\'>':
       print br.contents[0]
```

Comment: Please don't rely on string representation of objects for your code's logic.